# How to prevent weasyprint from cutting off summary table when using float right and page break?

Tags: html, css, weasyprint

I want to generate a credit note for the commissions of our sales reps with weasyprint and Django.

For the beginning i want to print all the invoiced items in one table and under this a summary-table. In the next step i will create the layout of the credit note.

html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/test_style.css' %}">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="invoice_items">
            <tr>
                <th>Belegart</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Beleg-Nr</th>
                <th>Kunde</th>
                <th>Artikel</th>
                <th>Menge</th>
                <th>Verkaufspreis</th>
                <th>Rechnungsbetrag</th>
            </tr>
            {% for item in items %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }} - {{ item.document.document_type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.document.invoice_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.document.invoice_number }}</td>
                    <td class="table_cell_left">{{ item.document.customer.name }}</td>
                    <td class="table_cell_left">{{ item.description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td class="table_cell_right">{{ item.item_price }} &euro;</td>
                    <td class="table_cell_right">{{ item.total_cost }} &euro;</td>
                </tr>
                {% if item.comment %}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="table_cell_left" colspan="8"><b>Anmerkung:</b> {{ item.comment }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <div class="summary">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table_cell_right">Summe Verkäufe/Gutschriften</th>
                    <td class="table_cell_right">{{ total_sales|floatformat:"2g" }} &euro;</td>
                </tr>
                    {% for key, value in summary.commission_rates.items %}
                        <tr>

                            <th class="table_cell_right">Provision {{ key }} %</th>
                            <td class="table_cell_right">{{ value|floatformat:"2g" }} &euro;</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% if 'special_items' in summary %}
                    {% for key, value in summary.special_items.items %}
                        <tr>
                            <th class="table_cell_right">{{ key }}</th>
                            <td class="table_cell_right">{{ value|floatformat:"2g" }} &euro;</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                <tr>
                    <th class="table_cell_right">Summe Provision ohne MwSt.</th>
                    <td class="table_cell_right">{{ commission_total|floatformat:"2g" }} &euro;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table_cell_right">Summe</th>
                    <td class="table_cell_right">{{ commission_total|floatformat:"2g" }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 5mm 5mm 5mm 15mm;

}

table, th, td {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 3px 5px 2px 5px;
    break-inside: auto;
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.items {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10mm;
}

.table_cell_left{
    text-align: left;
}

.table_cell_right{
    text-align: right;
}

.summary {
    page-break-before: auto;
    margin-top: 5mm;
    
}
```

This works...means it prints everything and, because there is not enough room for the complete summary-table, it makes a page break before it. The only "problem"... The summary-table is on the left side of the page ;-). If i add a `float: right:` to my .summary css it doesen't makes a page-break and prints the first line of the summary-table direct under the items table and ends the document. The "rest" of my summary-table is cut off.

So..what i expecting... If there is not enough room under the invoice_items-table there should be a page break and THEN the summary-table on the right side.